# Pollard’s p−1 algorithm: understanding of Berkeley paper

Tags: prime-factoring, factorization

[This paper](https://web.archive.org/web/20160812075833/https://math.berkeley.edu/~sagrawal/su14_math55/notes_pollard.pdf) explains about Pollard's p-1 factorization algorithm. I am having trouble understanding the case when factor found is equal to the input we go back and change 'a' (basically page 2 point 2 in the aforementioned paper).

1. Why we go back and increment 'a'?
2. Why we not go ahead and keep incrementing the factorial? It it because we keep going into the same cycle we have already seen?
3. Can I get all the factors using this same algorithm? Such as 49000 = 2^3 * 5^3 * 7^2. Currently I only get 7 and 7000. Perhaps I can use this get_factor() function recursively but I am wondering about the base cases.

   ```
   def gcd(a, b):
   if not b:
       return a
   return gcd(b, a%b)

   def get_factor(input):
       a = 2
       for factorial in range(2, input-1):
        '''we are not calculating factorial as anyway we need to find
           out the gcd with n so we do mod n and we also use previously
           calculate factorial'''
           a = a**factorial % input
           factor = gcd(a - 1, input)
           if factor == 1:
               continue
           elif factor == input:
               a += 1
           elif factor > 1:
               return factor

   n = 10001077
   p = get_factor(n)
   q = n/p
   print("factors of", n, "are", p, "and", q)
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linked paper is not a particularly good description of Pollard's *p* − 1 algorithm; most descriptions discuss smoothness bounds that make the algorithm much more practical. You might like to read [this page](https://www.rieselprime.de/ziki/P-1_factorization_method) at Prime Wiki. To answer your specific questions:

1. Why increment *a*? Because the original *a* doesn't work. In practice, most implementations don't bother; instead, a different factoring method, such as the elliptic curve method, is tried instead.
2. Why not increment the factorial? This is where the smoothness bound comes into play. Read the page at Mersenne Wiki for more details.
3. Can I get all factors? This question doesn't apply to the paper you linked, which assumes that the number being factored is a semi-prime with exactly two factors. The more general answer is "maybe." This is what happens at Step 3a of the linked paper, and choosing a new *a* may work (or may not). Or you may want to move to a different factoring algorithm.

Here is my simple version of the *p* − 1 algorithm, using *x* instead of *a*. The `while` loop computes the magical *L* of the linked paper (it's the least common multiple of the integers less than the smoothness bound *b*), which is the same calculation as the factorial of the linked paper, but done in a different way.

```
def pminus1(n, b, x=2):
    q = 0; pgen = primegen(); p = next(pgen)
    while p < b:
        x = pow(x, p**ilog(p,b), n)
        q, p = p, next(pgen)
    g = gcd(x-1, n)
    if 1 < g < n: return g
    return False
```

You can see it in action at http://ideone.com/eMPHtQ, where it factors 10001 as in the linked paper as well as finding a rather spectacular 36-digit factor of `fibonacci(522)`. Once you master that algorithm, you might like to move on to the two-stage version of the algorithm.

Comment: the link you linked in your answer doesn't talk about smoothness. Can you possibly add some description about your method of calculation of 'L' and add some link which talks about smoothness bounds. I will mark this answer after going through those.

Comment: "Less than a bound B1" is the concept of smoothness. I compute L as the least common multiple of the numbers less than the bound. Your link first gives L as a multiple of _p_ - 1, which is underspecified. Later, your link gives L as the product of all numbers less than R, which is overspecified.

Comment: B1 not chosen properly will fail this algorithm? In that case step 2 should be used. I think you are calculating the primes and raising it to some power(according to your linked url) so that it is less than the bound and seeing if the gcd of that number with the input number is greater than 1.

Comment: from your linked url it is mentioned that a should not be 2 but you used 2. I didn't understand why a should not be 2 and the reasoning in the url:When factoring a number of the form 2^p-1 (as in GIMPS) its prime factors have the form 2kp+1, so the value p must always be a factor of E. In this case the value of a must not be 2, because 2^E= 1 mod(N), so gcd(2^E - 1, N) = N, which is a trivial factor of N.

Comment: Most implementations use _a_ = 2; it is only a problem when factoring Mersenne numbers, which are easily recognized. And the algorithm may fail even if B1 is chosen "properly." If the algorithm fails for any reason, instead of choosing a different _a_, most factoring programs move on to a different algorithm, often the elliptic curve method because of its similarity to the _p_ - 1 method.